# How to detect if docker container crashed

Tags: java, docker

I am running a process every 5 minutes and checking to make sure every container. If the container does not respond I can flag it as down. I have the containers IP address and I loop through each ip and check if it responds to a ping. If not I flag it as down. Is there a better way to do this? My code:

```
@Transactional
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000 * 60)   //5 min
public void monitorHosts(){
    Iterable<Ncl> ncls = nclRepository.findAll();

    for(Ncl ncl: ncls){
        for(String host: ncl.getHosts()){
            Boolean isHostAlive = isHostAlive(host);
            if(!isHostAlive){
                Ncl nclWorking = nclRepository.findOne(ncl.getUuid());
                if(nclWorking != null){
                    Set<String> hosts = nclWorking.getHosts().stream().filter(x -> x.equals(host)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                    nclWorking.getHosts().clear();
                    nclWorking = nclRepository.save(nclWorking);
                    nclWorking.setHosts(hosts);
                    nclRepository.save(nclWorking);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private Boolean isHostAlive(String host){
    try{
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        boolean reachable = address.isReachable(10000);
        return reachable;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't it better to write a shell script on cron job?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve here. Are you testing that a set of host machines running Docker containers are up? Or are you trying to test on a particular host that a given set of containers are running?

Comment: Your second statement. Host = Container IP address. The host is the container ip address. I have a list of all the container ip addresses. Then I loop through the container ips. When I find a ip thats not reachable I remove it.

Comment: @CSK Yes, I can use a shell script. However I have no shell skills. Also, The shell script will need to interact with the database.

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on what you need to do with the information about your containers.

There is a number of monitoring solutions available, which can monitor your containers and notify some one if there are some troubles.

If you have to use this info in some application, then you can use some solutions like [Consul.io](https://www.consul.io/) and let them check your services statuses, not containers (in most cases man aware of the service availability in the container, not container itself). Or you can use [docker-api](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) for Java, because ICMP-protocol is not always a good solution, especially in distributed networks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `docker events`

extract from the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/#examples

use something like

`docker events --filter 'event=stop'`

Answer (score 1):

This is more obtrusive but is a nice one:

Using `HEALTHCHECK` that [docker provides](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck)

You can customize it for each application. Something like:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

Then you can check the health status as this:

```
docker inspect --format='{{json .State.Health}}' <container_id>
```

Or you can use `docker ps` and see the `STATUS` column:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                  NAMES
225426fc7c93        ubuntu              "tail -f /dev/null"      5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds (healthy)
```

Or you can query the docker API:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.24/containers/json
```

PS: You can set the healthcheck at `docker run` time (without modifying the Dockerfile). [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#healthcheck)